# How can I get all field values from a query with JOINed tables?

Tags: php, pear, mdb2

I have this elementary query:

```
SELECT d.description, o.code FROM order_positions AS o
LEFT JOIN article_descriptions AS d ON (o.article_id = d.article_id)
WHERE o.order_id = 1
```

and I'm using **`MDB2`** from `PEAR` to execute it and read the return values.

But somehow the result array always contains fields from the `order_positions` table **only**!, i.e. the result array looks like this

```
row[code] = 'abc123'
```

while I want it to look like this

```
row[description] = 'my description'
row[code] = 'abc123'
```

I already tried the following:

- Vary the order of the fields, i.e. `code` first, then `description`.
- Vary the order of the joined tables.
- Used full table names instead of aliases.
- Used the "MySQL join" instead (`SELECT FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id`)
- Used aliases with and without `AS`.

Some other facts:

- Executing this query in MySQL Query Browser works fine, all fields are returned.
- The `order_positions` table seems to be preferred, no matter what. When joining with additional tables I still only get fields from this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the cause:

Fields with **`NULL`** values are not added to the array. In my test scenario `description` was in fact null and hence was not available in the array.

I'll still keep this (embarrassing) question, just in case someone else has this problem in the future.

[Facepalm http://www.scienceblogs.de/frischer-wind/picard-facepalm-thumb-512x409.jpg](http://www.scienceblogs.de/frischer-wind/picard-facepalm-thumb-512x409.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT d.description, o.code 
FROM order_positions o, article_descriptions d 
WHERE o.order_id = 1 AND d.article_id = o.article_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not using [`fetchOne()`](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/latest/MDB2/MDB2_Result_Common.html#methodfetchOne) by mistake instead of [`fetchRow()`](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/latest/MDB2/MDB2_Result_Common.html#methodfetchRow)?

Could you post your PHP code?

Another possibility is that in your code you missed the comma:

```
SELECT a b
```

is the same as

```
SELECT a AS b
```

Comment: No, I'm using fetchRow. Wouldn't a missing comma result in a syntax error? I checked also with and without AS, both the same.